# Create new dataset by Google Translator

Tags: nlp, dataset, google-translation-api, farsi

I want to create dataset in Persian using google translation API. I want to use GoEmotions dataset. I do not know where should I start. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

use deep_translator library, we can use 2-lak request/day
[deep_translator](https://pypi.org/project/deep-translator/) yes,
it directly gets response from google translator